# Loop over array of objects for a feature

Tags: karate

My scenario is very common:
I create certain objects using the POST method. At the end of the feature I want to delete all the objects that I have retrieved from a GET operation

```
Feature:

Scenario: create cat
Given url demoBaseUrl
And path 'cats'
And request { name: '#(name)' } ## using table created many cats
When method post
Then status 200

Scenario: get all the cats
Given url demoBaseUrl
When method get
Then status 200
* def createdcats = $.cats[*].id

## this gives lets say 4 values Cat1,Cat2,Cat3,Cat4

##Now I want to use the DELETE method to delete the said cats, the DELETE operation takes a path param

Given url demoBaseUrl
And path 'cats'
When method delete
Then status 204
```

what is the parameter to be passed for looping over an array of `createdcats`

I had an idea of having a JS function, but then it will mean calling a feature from with js. Is it the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a re-usable delete feature and iterate it with multiple data set as you wish

create a new feature as below,

*deleteCats.feature*

```
Feature: delete cat feature
 Scenario: delete cat
  Given url demoBaseUrl 
  And path catId
  When method delete 
  Then status 204
```

Modify your main feature to call the above feature and run

*Main.feature*

```
Feature: cat feature
 Scenario: create cat 
  Given url demoBaseUrl 
  And path 'cats' 
  And request { name: '#(name)' } ## using table created many cats 
  When method post 
  Then status 200 
 Scenario: get all the cats 
  Given url demoBaseUrl 
  When method get 
  Then status 200 
  * def createdcats = $.cats[*].id
  * def createdcats = karate.mapWithKey(createdcats, 'catId')
  * def delCats = call read('deleteCats.feature') createdcats
```

Now the last 2 lines in the above code will create data for iteration and iterate the given feature for **n** number of times.